# I want to flip an image (with three channels RGB) horizontally just using array slicing. How can I do it with python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-slicing

I appreciate it if you can provide me with one-line code.

I used np.flip but I want a different approach to make it generalized.
This was my code: `np.flip(image, 1)`
I also used `np.fliplr(image)`.

Note: The image to be flipped has three channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flipped_image = image[:, ::-1, :]`